# Vertical line pushing text below it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am trying to create a desgin which is reposive in bootstrap were i have a vertical line coming down and then some text near it like this : [image]

I have manged to create this fine using bootstrap 3 grid system, the problem is , when i resize my window i was hoping the line would get smaller but what it does is push all my text below it , when i want the line to and text to stay exactly the same

HTML:

```
<header class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="verticalLine">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
             <div class="maintext">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h2>Some text goes here</h2><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h1 style="width: 600px;">Great design is simplicity and clarity</h1><br>
                <h2 style=" margin-top: -19px;">Idea - Design - launch</h2><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p style="font-size: 19px;">View profile ➡</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.verticalLine {
  border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
  height: 850px;
}
```

Fiddle link : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38278/) You can see when the window is shrunk all my text goes below it, even if i use media queries still nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to stop the line from wrapping the rest of the items:

```
.verticalLine {
  border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
  height: 850px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

.maintext {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

So something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38279/

Comment: Perfect thank you so much , and i guess when it goes to iPad /mobile i can use media queries to make the height smaller so it can fit the full screen size

Answer (score 0):

If you want that line to match your content exactly you can't set an explicit height. It will never grow or shrink beyond that.

Why not just this:

```
.maintext {
  border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

You'll have to either do that, or place the content element inside of the line element.

Comment: For design purpose i need the line to be the full height of the screen from top to bottom so this wont work

Comment: I mean i could use an image instead maybe?

Comment: Just because i need to put padding between the text and line

Comment: You can just add a `padding-left` to your container if you need to move the line over. I think you'll have to clarify your use-case a little more, I don't really understand ultimately what you're hoping to accomplish. should the text also move down if the window is resized?.